# How do I avoid uploading my private firebase admin sdk info, while still maintaining functionality?

Tags: python, credentials, firebase-admin

I have a python script to handle my Firebase Cloud Messaging server, using the firebase admin SDK.

In another file I have the private info such as:

`private_key_id`
`private_key`

etc.

How do I then upload the python script(which requires this sensitive file to allow script to run) to some type of server, without compromising that private info.